# onActivityResult() never called from tabbed activity in android

Tags: android

I am working with tabbed activity in android. In my image tab I am trying to pick image from gallery and by taking new photo. but it doesn't work out.I applied the solutions given in other question but in vain. Now I am posting code with correction. please help for solution. here is my code.Here I am using 1888 as Code=1888

```html
if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    captureCameraImage(Code);
                } 

 private void captureCameraImage(int CAMERA_PHOTO) {
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "POST_IMAGE.jpg");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        imageToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        AddRecipe intent=(AddRecipe)getParent();
        intent.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO);
    }

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: How is the `launchMode` are you using for this `activity`?

Comment: I didn't declare in manifist

Comment: Maybe parent activity overriding `onActivityResult`?

Comment: not @betorcs it's not. this is only in this activity

Comment: is CAMERA_PHOTO value 1888?

Comment: yes it's value is 1888

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117105/discussion-between-betorcs-and-junaid).

Answer (score 0):

You must use one `activity` and if you need tabs you must use `fragments` for tabs and if you need to take picture you need to define all methods in `activity` and call them from `fragments`. This is the correct way ) start activity for result must be called and served from activity context.

Answer (score 0):

define a baseActivity and make all your activities implements from it.
try if onActivityResult of baseActivity  called